# Twilio breaking text messages into many messages

Tags: sms

Please find attached image.

This never happened before and it was working perfectly fine yesterday.

However, as of today messages are being split into several messages to the ooont that the messages are no longer legible. Any idea why this is happening? Is it a twilio issue or a service provider issue?

[image]